# Adding Woocommerce Brands names to cart item product names

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, cart, checkout

I use the Woocommerce Brands plugin and I would like to add the Brand to each product when it is in the cart, like it displays variations.

So Product Name, and then 
Size: XXX
Colour: XXX
Brand: XXX

I have tried a few ways of doing it but I can't seem to get it to work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Update 2** - *Code enhanced and optimized (April 2019)*

Now the way to add brand name(s) just as the product attributes names + values in cart items, is also possible using this custom function hooked in **`woocommerce_get_item_data`** filter hook.

The code will be a little different (but the same to get the brand data):

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_get_item_data', 'customizing_cart_item_data', 10, 2 );
function customizing_cart_item_data( $cart_item_data, $cart_item ) {
    $product = $cart_item['data']; // The WC_Product Object

    // Get product brands as a coma separated string of brand names
    $brands =  implode(', ', wp_get_post_terms($cart_item['product_id'], 'product_brand', ['fields' => 'names']))

    if( ! emty( $brands ) ) {
        $cart_item_data[] = array(
            'name'      => __( 'Brand', 'woocommerce' ),
            'value'     => $brands,
            'display'   => $brands,
        );
    }
    return $cart_item_data;
}
```

*Code goes in function.php file of your active child theme (or theme) or also in any plugin file.*

---

Here is the way to add brand name(s) to the product name in cart items using this custom function hooked in **`woocommerce_cart_item_name`** filter hook.

As they can be multiple brands set for 1 product, we will display them in a coma separated string *(when there is more than 1)*.

Here is the code:

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_cart_item_name', 'customizing_cart_item_name', 10, 3 );
function customizing_cart_item_name( $product_name, $cart_item, $cart_item_key ) {
    $product   = $cart_item['data']; // The WC_Product Object
    $permalink = $product->get_permalink(); // The product permalink

    // Get product brands as a coma separated string of brand names
    $brands = implode(', ', wp_get_post_terms($cart_item['product_id'], 'product_brand', ['fields' => 'names']));

    if ( is_cart() && ! empty( $brands ) )
        return sprintf( '<a href="%s">%s | %s</a>', esc_url( $product_permalink ), $product->get_name(), $brand );
    elseif ( ! empty( $brands ) )
        return  $product_name . ' | ' . $brand;
    else return $product_name;
}
```

*Code goes in function.php file of your active child theme (or theme) or also in any plugin file.*

All code is tested on Woocommerce 3+ and works.

Comment: Thanks @LoicTheAztec , that is great. Is it possible to have the brand look like a variation instead of in the title? http://prntscr.com/go7wep

Comment: @JamesDeadman this is not the same code for that … I have to update my answer… I will need some minutes to test and do the change.

Comment: Thanks very much, that's exactly what I was looking for.