# Display Product Brand and Name in Woocommerce Orders and email notifications

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, orders, taxonomy-terms

In WooCommerce I have enabled [Perfect Brands Woocommerce](https://wordpress.org/plugins/perfect-woocommerce-brands/) plugin to display product Brands. I would like the Brand to appear before the product name throughout the whole cycle (single product page, cart, checkout, mini cart, order and emails).

I am able to display the related brand before the product name in cart and checkout pages, using *"[Adding Woocommerce Brands names to cart item product names](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46350430/adding-woocommerce-brands-names-to-cart-item-product-names/46354703#46354703)"* answer code lightly changed *(using `pbw-brand` plugin custom taxonomy)*:

```
// Display product brand in Cart and checkout pages
add_filter( 'woocommerce_cart_item_name', 'customizing_cart_item_name', 10, 3 );
function customizing_cart_item_name( $product_name, $cart_item, $cart_item_key ) {
    $product =  $cart_item['data']; // The product
    $product_id =  $cart_item['product_id']; // The product id

    // Loop through the product brand names
    foreach( wp_get_post_terms( $product_id, 'pwb-brand' ) as $wp_term )
        $brand_names[] = $wp_term->name; // Set the brand names in an array

    $brand_names_str = implode( ', ', $brand_names); // Set the brand names in a comma separated string array

    $brand = $brand_names_str;
    $product_permalink = $product->get_permalink( $cart_item );

    if ( is_cart() && count( $brand_names ) > 0 )
        return sprintf( '<a href="%s">%s %s</a>', esc_url( $product_permalink ), $brand, $product->get_name()  );
    elseif ( count( $brand_names ) > 0 )
        return  $brand . ' ' . $product_name;
    else return $product_name;
}
```

But I don't know how to implement that for the Order and Email notifications.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have revisited your question code and added some additional functions to display the product brand on Order pages and on email notifications:

```
// Utility: Get the product brand term names (from the product ID)
function wc_get_product_brand( $product_id ) {
   return implode(', ', wp_get_post_terms($product_id, 'pwb-brand', ['fields' => 'names']));
}

// Display product brand in Cart and checkout pages
add_filter( 'woocommerce_cart_item_name', 'customizing_cart_item_name', 10, 3 );
function customizing_cart_item_name( $product_name, $cart_item, $cart_item_key ) {
    $product = $cart_item['data'];          // The WC_Product Object
    $permalink = $product->get_permalink(); // The product permalink

    if( $brand = wc_get_product_brand( $cart_item['product_id'] ) ) {
        if ( is_cart() )
            return sprintf('<a href="%s">%s %s</a>', esc_url($permalink), $brand, $product->get_name());
        else
            return  $brand . ' ' . $product_name;
    }
    return $product_name;
}

// Display product brand in order pages and email notification
add_filter( 'woocommerce_order_item_name', 'customizing_order_item_name', 10, 2 );
function customizing_order_item_name( $product_name, $item ) {
    $product = $item->get_product();        // The WC_Product Object
    $permalink = $product->get_permalink(); // The product permalink

    if( $brand = wc_get_product_brand( $item->get_product_id() ) ) {
        if ( is_wc_endpoint_url() )
            return sprintf('<a href="%s">%s %s</a>', esc_url($permalink), $brand, $product->get_name());
        else
            return  $brand . ' ' . $product_name;
    }
    return $product_name;
}
```

Code goes in function.php file of your active child theme (or active theme). Tested and works.

Comment: You are awesome dude! Thank you so much!

Comment: Is it also possible to display the brand in the backend order details and the Products section?

Comment: @FarrukhKarimov This should be done differently (not sure that is possible to display the brand in the product name) as order items are dynamic editable data. So you should ask a new question please.