# How to get the brand name of product in WooCommerce

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, custom-taxonomy, taxonomy-terms

i need get the brand name of product , i have this code

```
$product = wc_get_product();

  $type = $product->get_type();      
  $name = (string)$product->get_name();
  $id = (int)$product->get_id(); 
  $sku  = (int)$product->get_sku(); 
  $precio = (int)$product->get_price();

$brand_name = $product->get_brand(); ---> ???
```

i get this attributes but i don't know how catch the brand name, is there another way ?

[image]

Thanks!

Comment: seems you are using plugins for the brand, can you name that plugin? I assume brand will stay as terms of that certain taxonomy...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `get_the_terms`

```
get_the_terms($product->get_id(),'pa_brand')
```

Answer (score 11):

Is better to use [`wc_get_post_terms()`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_get_post_terms) from a product ID (that allows to get term names instead of WP_Term Objects) and depending on what plugin you are using, the taxonomy will be different:

- `product_brand` for Woocommerce Brands plugin
- `yith_product_brand` for YITH WooCommerce Brands plugin
- `pa_brand` for a custom product attribute

So for example with Woocommerce Brands plugin you will use:

```
$product_id  = get_the_id();
$product     = wc_get_product( $product_id );

$taxonomy    = `product_brand`;
$brand_names = wp_get_post_terms( $product_id, $taxonomy, array( 'fields' => 'names' ) );

// Get the brand name
$brand_name = reset( $brand_names );
```

Related:

- [Display category and brand name on single product page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51325042/display-category-and-brand-name-on-single-product-page/51330185#51330185)
- [Display Product Brand and Name in Woocommerce Orders and email notifications](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55540381/display-product-brand-and-name-in-woocommerce-orders-and-email-notifications/55542584#55542584)
- [Adding Woocommerce Brands names to cart item product names](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46350430/adding-woocommerce-brands-names-to-cart-item-product-names/46354703#46354703)

Answer (score 2):

Thanks for the help , I used this code and it works.

```
$terms = get_the_terms( get_the_ID(), 'product_brand' );

foreach ( $terms as $term ){
    if ( $term->parent == 0 ) {
        $brand_name=  $term->slug;
    }
}  
echo $brand_name;
```

Comment: Yes, it depends upon plugin as @LoicTheAztec explained

Answer (score 2):

If you use Woocommerce Brands Plugin:https://docs.woocommerce.com/document/woocommerce-brands/

You can use the next funtion:

```
echo get_brands();
```

the plugin includes a function to get the brands, the next lines are declarated in the next plugin file and directory woocommerce-brands/includes/wc-brands-functions/line-64 to 81

```php
function get_brands( $post_id = 0, $sep = ', ', $before = '', $after = '' ) {
    global $post;

    if ( ! $post_id ) {
        $post_id = $post->ID;
    }

    return get_the_term_list( $post_id, 'product_brand', $before, $sep, $after );
}
```